# Paging Control vs UITabBar on iOS

Tags: gui-design, ios, human-interface-guideline, tab-bar, page-control

This is the starting page of my App.

[image: first page]

`Trips`, `Chats` and `Settings` at the bottom are in `UITabBar`

If user clicks on a trip/group, (s)he is leaded to the following Group Home. (This page is 'pushed' on 'Trips' `NavigationVC`)

[image: Group Home page]

Now I want the bottom options `Timeline`, `Plans`, `Conversation` and `Budget` to be working like `UITabBarOptions`.
But this is against Apple UX Guidelines of using `UITabBarController`, as there should be just one TabBarController throughout the App.

The other alternative is to use PagingView Controller which looks like this:

[image: pagecontrol]

But this doesn't look as simple as the Tab Bar. What UX should I go with, or is there a better UX design to present this whole scenario?

Comment: You need to map this out as a list of functions and operations, with respective content lengths, so you can see this properly, and then explain the problem to yourself better. Visually expressing it will probably present the solutions.

Comment: Thanks @Confused, I was looking for a design which is commonly followed so the first time users find intuitive to use it.

Comment: For anyone to suggest that, they'd have to understand what you're trying to present. The above question layout makes that impossible.

Comment: Until you can articulate the question REALLY well, there's no way for the question to make sense to you, let alone someone else. And it's at the point where you can really understand what you're attempting to do that it often becomes obvious HOW to do something.

Comment: OK, I will edit to add more info and visuals to the question.

Comment: Not just that. Sit down with a pencil and paper, and EXACTLY map out your problems, and your goals, and your desires, and deeply look into the problem. When you do that, you'll see things as they really are, and won't be making guesses based on something that's sort of close, but not the same, and trying to hotwire something to match your unique problem.

Comment: Flow diagram MULTIPLE ways for things to happen. Really dive into it. Designing interactive experiences requires a really deep and innately complete understanding of all potential pathways, and all potential limits. It's much bigger than the simplistic nonsense of "design patterns", HIG and other guff would have you believe. And you will always have to make weighted, calculated compromises and balance these against objectives and initiatives within the purposes of the app, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As you said:

> But this is against Apple UX Guidelines of using UITabBarController, as there should be just one TabBarController throughout the App.

Therefore bottom tabbar is out since you already have a main tabbar.

Since I don't have the full back story, I'm assuming *Timeline, Plans, Conservation* and *Budgets* are the page sub-links.

Here are some common best practices for mobile sub navigation links:

- Arranged the most important links from left to right.
- Do not hide the links.
- Icons take up space and mobile has limited screen estate. If its preventing you from showing more content, you might want to consider removing them.
- Navigation links should be obvious to the user, tab or colored links are great choice.
- Sufficient paddings around the link to make it easy for the fingers to tap on.

I would go for the paging view controller.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE5syK.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

You might also want to consider this approach to surface more content:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr467w.png)</sup>

Unless your target group are really tech and design savvy, I would a adopt a more common and conventional way of styling my sub-links.

Answer (score 0):

**First**: Not what I would recommend, but what it seems more like what you have in mind.

There is a common UI to do this, and its the `UISegmentedView`,

[image: AppStore Screenshot]

**Second**: I think a scrolling UI with all the info on the same view, grouping relevant info is better.  Let me give you some examples.

[image][image]
[image]

I have circled every category, this be the way to *show* your trip.  Notice that some of this are just previews/summaries of the information, you have to go to a different view controller to have more detail.

Also your chat would need to be on another view controller as chats don't go inside tabs usually.

I would suggest something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwufdr.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>